# How to pass an url by a rest api URL string

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have a table a with columns like pageId and page_name where values are inserted line [1,https://google.com] and so on.

Now i created an api that takes the URL and returns the pageid, so now the scenario is like:

```
localhost:8080/api/v1/page/https://google.com
```

whenever i am trying to pass it via Postman is is showing **Could not send response** can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: url syntax doesn't seem correct.

Comment: In such a case it's better to use parameters than path values. But anyway, try to URI-encode the URL.

Comment: Hi @RealSkeptic , it worked, as i used parameter instead of path variable. Thank you so much for your quick reply. please answer the question so that i can accept it, that could help others.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have reserved chars in your query param.

Consider [encoding](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/) your text.

So:
`http://www.google.com`

will become:
`http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> localhost:8080/api/v1/page/https://google.com
> ```

According url format documentation (see for example [this article](https://www.urlencoder.io/learn/#:%7E:text=A%20URL%20is%20composed%20from,%22%20%2C%20%22%7E%22%20) )- impossible use reserved chars (: and /) as parameters. I reccoment use something like

> ```
> localhost:8080/api/v1/page/google.com
> ```

And add "https://" in service

or use

> ```
> localhost:8080/api/v1/page/https~~google.com
> ```

And replaced "~~" to "://".